# javascript setting the size of a window

Tags: javascript

I am trying to set a browser window to a particular size using the code below.  When I load the page the size doesn't change.  I am looking at it through firefox,but I also looked at it through safari but still there is no change.  I am following several examples that i found online, and it seems like i am doing everything that was in the tutorial. What am i doing wrong????

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style>
body 
{
background-image:url('tri_tespic.jpg');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-attachment:fixed;
background-position:center; 

}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeScreenSize(w,h)
     {
       window.resizeTo( w,h )
     }
</script>
</head>

<body onload="changeScreenSize(818,50)">

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it isn't possible to resize the window when it is top-level (i.e. not a popup)

Comment: This is correct for all modern browsers. Some really old browsers let you do it, but it was something of a security issue.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly A short answer is not necessarily a low quality answer, and it this case it address exactly the question. If you don't agree on a technical basis that shouldn't be a reason for flagging as "not an answer".

Comment: @Javier ah my mistake, I read it as "Is it possible to resize...". Serves me right for going on SO later than usual!

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Np bud, all a misunderstanding then.